# Is this possible a Rectangle contains children?

Tags: java, textarea, javafx

With JavaFX, I want to create some "post-it" which are composed by  a rectangle for the shape and a TextArea to write something in this rectangle. I'm a beginner with JavaFX and I want to know if my rectangle could contain the TextArea to only have to move the rectangle when I want to move the entire object.

Thank you with advance, sry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rectangle cannot have children, but there are many components that can be styled to look like a post-it that can.

You could for example use a Group, a VBox, a StackPane or a BorderPane for your post-it, and put a label or text area inside that.  They will all move as one when you move the parent.